# Get all values of a specific column of a specific content type

Tags: column, query

I have a custom content type. In this content type, I have a text column (Mycolumn).

In a site collection, I have several instances of list bound to this content type.

**Is there a way to retrieve all values of this column in all the site collection?**

My goal is to build a webpart that suggest, in a drop down list, all existing value, in order to build a CAML query and display results.

I'm using SP2010 Standard, and a search server is setup (if it can helps).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a possible solution to solve the problem:

```
    private IEnumerable<T> GetDistinctValues<T>(SPSite site, int listTemplateId, SPContentTypeId contentType, string fieldName)
    {
        var query = new SPSiteDataQuery
        {
            Lists = "<Lists ServerTemplate='" + listTemplateId + "' />",
            ViewFields = "<FieldRef Name='" + fieldName + "' Type='Text'/>",
            Query = "<Where><BeginsWith><FieldRef Name='ContentTypeId' /><Value Type='ContentTypeId'>" + SyndicateNewsContentTypeId + "</Value></BeginsWith></Where>" +
            "<OrderBy><FieldRef Name='" + fieldName + "' /></OrderBy>",
            Webs = "<Webs Scope='SiteCollection' />"
        };

        var result = site.RootWeb.GetSiteData(query);
        var resultView = new DataView(result);
        var distinct = resultView.ToTable(true, fieldName);

        foreach (DataRow item in distinct.Rows)
        {
            yield return (T)item[0];
        }
    }
```

Basically, the idea is to issue a `SPSiteDataQuery` that is filtering against my custom content type. Then, I use the `DataView.ToTable` method, to get distinct values.

Answer (score 1):

The [`SPContentTypeUseage`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spcontenttypeusage%28v=office.14%29.aspx) class may be of help to you here.  It has a static method `GetUsages(SPContentType)` that will return a list of `SPContentTypeUsage` objects.  Through those objects, you can determine the specific lists that use your content type, open the lists, and get all the values of your column.

Comment: I was hoping that there some kind of magical method that can do the job. Your suggestion will help me anyways. Thanks. I'll have to implement a bit of cache, but this will be a good first step.